# How to Use Lookup Table to Set Tracking Code Based on Domain in Google Tag Manager V2

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm using the new Google Tag Manager interface and having troubles understanding how to implement a lookup table to achieve what seems to be a common variable.

When domain equals [x] set google analytics tracking id to [y]

I've found a few articles on setting this up but they are all using the older macro interface and the new interface is different enough that I can't wrap my head around it.

this article details exactly what I am attempting to achieve (Multi-account or multi-property container)

http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-lookup-table-macro/

What I'm getting caught on is the extra bit of logic that seems to be lost in the new interface. See highlighted in my screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the GTM V2 lookup table, your Input Variable would be your hostname. Use the built-in variable {{Page Hostname}} for this.

Then the Input would be the hostname, ie. www.example1.com, and Output would be the property ID. It would look something like this:

[image]

You should also include a default just in case.

Comment: Ah this makes total sense now that I can visually see it. Thank you!

Comment: How to add same domain with different tracking code in Lookup table.Please help me into this?